# Can Facebook Ban or disqualify my FB app if it's not exactly fitting a specific game Category

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

We are developing a mobile app game that heavily depends on Facebook,
friends, invites, scores and more. This functionality only available for FB apps in game category.

We are submitting it as a Card Game, 
The game play is around cards, a winner wins score 
the game also includes shopping,
because the end result is a coupon + game points.

We are afraid that when we will submit our app for Facebook verification,
they could change our category or disapprove the app.

Does any one got experience with this, 
can it happen or we got nothing to worry about ?

Thanks in advance for any insights,

Max

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming and would require Facebook Support to answer properly.

Comment: Yes they can disapprove or change category

Comment: @Ben Facebook support are not questions like that, maybe they don't care or don't want to reveal their logic.  i Asked developers who already developed apps for facebook and experienced banning or disqualification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out what will get you banned or not banned, refer to their [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy).